# How to use a variable in testng.xml file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

i have following xml file in which i want to create variables and use them in all the test tags. 
In below xml file, the property tag is what i tried to create a variable which is not working.
I want to create two variables env and browser in this testng.xml and use them within the same testng.xml.
Following is my code.

````
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="VW SRSTN-1152 suite">
    <property name = "env" value = "qa">qa</property>
    <property name = "browser" value = "firefox">firefox</property>
    <listeners>
           <listener
                class-name="com.utility.CustomTestNGReporter" />
     </listeners>
    <test name="Test-1">
    <parameter name = "environment" value="${env}"/>
    <parameter name = "browser" value="${browser}"/>
        <classes>
         <class name="com.TC1"/> 
         <class name="com.TC2"/>
        </classes>
   </test> <!-- Test1 -->
   <test name="Test-2">
    <parameter name = "environment" value="${env}"/>
    <parameter name = "browser" value="${browser}"/>
        <classes>
         <class name="com.TC1"/> 
         <class name="com.TC2"/> 
        </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test2 -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this,

```
<suite name="Parameter test Suite" verbose="1">
<!-- This parameter will be passed to every test in this suite -->
<parameter name="suite-param" value="suite level parameter" />

<test name="Parameter Test one">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.myclass1Here"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Parameter Test two">
    <!-- This parameter will be passed this test only -->
    <parameter name="test-two-param" value="Test two parameter" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.myclass2Here"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Parameter Test three">
    <!-- Overriding suite level parameter -->
    <parameter name="suite-param" value="overiding suite parameter" />
    <!-- Test specific parameter -->
    <parameter name="test-three-param" value="test three parameter" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.myClass3Here"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

depends upon your requirement you can use suite level par or test level par. You can override suite level par in test also

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Actually in my case i need to pass parameter from suite to all the tests and from tests to all the classes. So eventually i will modify parameters at suite level and run all the classes with those parameters only.

Comment: Then give at suite level only. All tests will take those parameters. Why need to specify at Test level then?

Comment: In class use like this  @Test
   @Parameters("myName")
   public void parameterTest(String myName) {
      System.out.println("Parameterized value is : " + myName);
   }

Comment: Yes got it. I removed test level parameters and it is working as expected. Thanks again for your help.